# Covariance of random Gaussian field on a sphere

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider the Hamiltonian of the $p-$spin spherical glass model
$$H_{N,p} = \frac{1}{N^{\frac{p-1}{2}}} \sum_{i_1, ..., i_p = 1}^{N} J_{i_1, ..., i_p} \sigma_{i_1} \cdot \cdot \ \cdot \sigma_{i_p}$$
where $\mathbf{\sigma} = (\sigma_1, ... , \sigma_N) \in S^{N-1} ( \sqrt{N})$ and $J_{i_1, ... , i_p} \sim \mathcal{N} (0 , \cdot)$ are independent centered Gaussian normal random variables. The constrain on the vector $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma_i ^2 = 1.$$
How can I find the covariance
$$\mathbb{E}[H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma}), H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma '})]?$$
The answer is
$$\mathbb{E}[H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma}), H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma '})] = N^{1-p} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sigma_i \sigma ' _i \right )^p$$
but I do not see where this comes from. It should be some straightforward expected value calculation of tensors but I can't seem to do it. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first observation is that
$$
H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma})  H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma '})
= \frac{1}{N^{\frac{p-1}{2}}} \sum_{i_1, \dots, i_p = 1}^{N} J_{i_1, \dots, i_p} \sigma_{i_1}\dots\sigma_{i_p} \frac{1}{N^{\frac{p-1}{2}}} \sum_{j_1, \dots, j_p = 1}^{N} J_{j_1, \dots, j_p} \sigma_{j_1} \dots \sigma_{j_p}
$$
and that $\mathbb E\left[J_{i_1,\dots, i_p} J_{j_1, \dots, j_p} \right]=1$ if $(i_1,\dots,i_p)=(j_1,\dots,j_p)$ and $0$ otherwise. Therefore,
$$
\mathbb E\left[H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma})  H_{N,p} (\mathbf{\sigma '})\right]
=\frac 1{N^{p-1}}\sum_{i_1, ..., i_p = 1}^{N}\sigma_{i_1} \dots\sigma_{i_p} \sigma'_{i_1} \dots\sigma'_{i_p}.
$$
Grouping the terms according to their index of summation and using $\sum_{i,i'=1}^N a_{i}b_{i'}=\sum_{i=1}^Na_i\sum_{i'=1}^Nb_{i'}$ allows to conclude.

Comment: Thank you! How did you know that the expected value of the product of the $Js$ is $1$? If the variance is $1$ I understand but that is not given.

Comment: I missed that point. Indeed, without information on the variance of $J_{i_1,\dots,i_p}$, it seems that everything can happen.

Comment: Hi @DavideGiraudo. Here is a [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4643937/121671) that might be of your interest.